# Ruby on Rails send params on devise registration and login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, devise

I need to send on my Devise registration form params of the actual language that the user selected and that I keep in the route as params[:lang].

I have a custom controller because I am validating a reCaptcha(that part works).

So I have in my routes:

```
    devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }

    devise_for :users do
         root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
         get "/" => "devise/registrations#new"
         post '/' => 'registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
         match '/', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
         get "/logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
    end

    #Sign
    match '/:lang/:sec/sign' => 'frontend#sign', :as => :sign
```

In my register form:

```
   <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => 
   registration_path(resource_name, :lang => params[:lang], :sec => params[:sec])) 
   do |f| %>
```

And i have two controllers, one for users and another for administrators, on successful login, Devise goes to the users controller, callers Restringido and wonders whether the user is validates as admin or only a common user.

In my restringido controller:

```
    class RestringidoController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :verify_is_user

    def verify_is_user
       if current_user.try(:admin?)
       #redireccionar a backend
       redirect_to :controller => "backend", :action => "index"
    elsif current_user
       #mantenerte en este controlador
    else
       redirect_to :controller => "frontend", :action => "sign"
    end
```

And my backend controller for administrators:

```
    before_filter :verify_is_admin

    def verify_is_admin
       if current_user.admin?
    else
       redirect_to root_path
    end
```

And the error is:

```
    No route matches {:controller=>"frontend", :action=>"sign"}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on which version of Rails and Devise you are using? Did you already modify your routes.rb according to the Devise Examples & Readme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route:

```
match '/:lang/:sec/sign' => 'frontend#sign', :as => :sign
```

requires the `:lang` variable to be set, and you have not provided a default value. So this call in the controller:

```
redirect_to :controller => "frontend", :action => "sign"
```

will fail to match the route, because you have not provided a `:lang` variable

To fix this, you can either provide the `:lang` value in the controller eg:

```
redirect_to :controller => "frontend", :action => "sign", :lang => (params[:lang] || DEFAULT_LANG)
```

or have a default value in the route.